# Eclipse user library variables and jar export to WEB-INF/lib

Tags: eclipse, classpath

I have a workspace with nearly fifty web projects in it.  In an effort to streamline classpath entries, I have created a user library variable and added all required jars to it.  Next, I removed the individual classpath (build) entries from each of the fifty projects and replaced them with my single user library variable.  Everything was going great until I deployed one of my projects from Eclipse to Tomcat and discovered the list of jars on the user library variable were *not* being copied to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Does anyone know of a way to specify that these libraries get copied to the deployment source?  I experimented with the Java EE Module Dependency tab, but the jars were not copied even after selecting the name of the user library set.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

From my experience, Eclipse is not good at packaging all external Jars for you, but FatJar will do the trick.